# Gravando textos formatado no banco de dados firebird

Tags: delphi, firebird, delphi-berlin, delphi-tokyo, delphi-seatle

Eu sei que tem uma pergunta parecida com essa mais é para a `tag C#`

- Tem com Salvar o texto formatado em um `TRichEdit` no ***Firebird***?
- Qual seria o *tipo de dados* do `field` que possibilita essa gravação?

Comment: O texto de uma TRichEdit nao deixa de ser uma string normal certo? Tem as tags de formataçao mas é uma string na mesma...

Comment: Mais se eu salvar o `TRichEdit` no banco e pedi para mostra em outro `TRichEdit` ele não mostra formatado.

Comment: Eu uso um componente da biblioteca Jedi (JvDbRichEdit) que faz esse trabalho de forma transparente. Tem também um JvRichEditToHtml.

Comment: terei de desinstalar o RXLib para instalar o JEDI?

Comment: RXLib e JEDI são independentes você pode ter os dois instalados, aconselho utilizar o JEDI.

Comment: não consegui instalar o JEDI...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem como salvar o texto de um RichEdit formatado em qualquer banco de dados ou arquivo. Para salvar em banco de dados, você preferencialmente deve utilizar o tipo de campo **Blob**.

No Firebird, existe o Blob Text e o Blob Binary. Para este caso, utilize o **Blob Binary**.

Veja a seguir o código para salvar o conteúdo de um TRichEdit em um TBlobField utilizando uma Query no Delphi:

```
procedure TForm1.BtnSalvarRichTextEmBlobClick(Sender: TObject);
var M: TMemoryStream;
begin
  M := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    RichEdit.Lines.SaveToStream(M); //salvar o RichEdit em stream

    //Gravar blob na tabela via SQL
    QWrite.SQL.Text := 'insert into Tabela1 (ID, Rich) values (:ID, :Rich)';
    QWrite.ParamByName('ID').AsInteger := 1;
    QWrite.ParamByName('Rich').LoadFromStream(M, ftBlob);
    QWrite.ExecSQL;

  finally
    M.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Veja agora como ficaria a função para carregar este registro já salvo em tabela de volta para o RichEdit:

```
procedure TForm1.BtnCarregarDoBancoParaRichTextClick(Sender: TObject);
var M: TMemoryStream;
begin
  //Carregar a Query
  QLoad.SQL.Text := 'select Rich from Tabela1 where ID = :ID';
  QLoad.ParamByName('ID').AsInteger := 1;
  QLoad.Open;

  M := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    TBlobField( QLoad.FieldByName('Rich') ).SaveToStream(M); //salvar o field em um stream
    M.Position := 0; //esta linha é necessária pois ao salvar o stream ele estará na posição final
    RichEdit.Lines.LoadFromStream(M); //carregar o stream para o RichEdit
  finally
    M.Free;
  end;
end;
```